# How to get a substring with special characters in batch file?

Tags: string, batch-file, special-characters

I'm trying to remove a part of a string with special characters.

The string looks like: `<abc>123</abc>`
I want to extract only `123`

I've tried

```
set substr=<abc>
%my_string:substr=%
```

and removing character by position

`set result=%my_string:~5,-6%`

but neither works. Someone can help me?

ps. I'm new in batch.
sorry for the english.

Comment: `for /F "TOKENS=2 delims=<>" %%G in ("%substr%") do echo %%G`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delayed expansion and double quoting of strings are the methods needed here.

The use of the for loop is just as a way of defining all substrings to be removed in the one line.

```
@echo off

Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "string=<abc>123</abc>"
For %%A in ("<abc>" "</abc>") do Set "string=!string:%%~A=!"
Echo(!string!
pause
```